# get Local IP address of Client Computer by javascript in XPages

Tags: javascript, xpages

I need to find client local Ip address and then need to write it in a document. this code below works fine but only Chrome and Firefox. It does not work on IE.
is there any way to make it work on IE? I also get IP address of computer then save it a some log db when a user logins to.

```
<h3 id="list"> <xp:text escape="true" id="localIP"
    value="#{sessionScope.localIP}">
 </xp:text></h3> 

 <xp:scriptBlock id="scriptBlock1">
        <xp:this.value><![CDATA[var RTCPeerConnection = window.RTCPeerConnection || window.webkitRTCPeerConnection || window.mozRTCPeerConnection;

if (RTCPeerConnection) (function () 
{
    var rtc = new RTCPeerConnection({iceServers:[]});
    if (1 || window.mozRTCPeerConnection) 
    { 
        rtc.createDataChannel('', {reliable:false});
    };

    rtc.onicecandidate = function (evt) 
    {
        if (evt.candidate) grepSDP("a="+evt.candidate.candidate);
    };
    rtc.createOffer(function (offerDesc) 
    {
        grepSDP(offerDesc.sdp);
        rtc.setLocalDescription(offerDesc);
    }, function (e) { console.warn("offer failed", e); });

    var addrs = Object.create(null);
    addrs["0.0.0.0"] = false;
    function updateDisplay(newAddr) 
    {
        if (newAddr in addrs) return;
        else addrs[newAddr] = true;
        var displayAddrs = Object.keys(addrs).filter(function (k) { return addrs[k]; });
        document.getElementById('list').textContent = displayAddrs.join(" or perhaps ") || "n/a";
    }

    function grepSDP(sdp) 
    {
        var hosts = [];
        sdp.split('\r\n').forEach(function (line) 
        { 
            if (~line.indexOf("a=candidate")) {      
                var parts = line.split(' '),       
                    addr = parts[4],
                    type = parts[7];
                if (type === 'host') updateDisplay(addr);
            } else if (~line.indexOf("c=")) {  
                var parts = line.split(' '),
                    addr = parts[2];
                updateDisplay(addr);
            }
        });
    }
})(); else {
    document.getElementById('list').innerHTML = "n/a";  //"<code>ifconfig | grep inet | grep -v inet6 | cut -d\" \" -f2 | tail -n1</code>";
    document.getElementById('list').nextSibling.textContent = "Displayed Automaticly";
}
]]></xp:this.value>
    </xp:scriptBlock>
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/391979/how-to-get-clients-ip-address-using-javascript-only

Comment: What about the IP in the HTTP Request?

Comment: It's the local IP. The result is what i need. Still it does not work on IE :(
That's what you meant? right?

Comment: Then the comment form @PerHenrikLausten won't help you, it would just return the ip of the proxy.

Comment: The IE object *window.msRTCPeerConnection* does not work either.